# SQL Server comparing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with Settlement details and I need a report in SSRS that returns settlement items with settlement date yesterday or older. I know this is trivial but there is something I am doing wrong and would appreciate help

This is for Microsoft SQL Server and basic table for simplification

```
Select
    SETL.SettlementDay as SD,
    SETL.Amount as Amount,
    SETL.quantity as Q
From
    Setlement as SETL
Where
    SETL.SettlementDate < getdate()
```

This doesn't work for me. I expect the output would be settlements with settlement date older or equal to yesterday

Thanks

Comment: What is the output you do get? Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What **datatype** is your `SettlementDate` in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want yesterday or older, then use:

```
where SETL.SettlementDate < convert(date, getdate())
```

The conversion to `date` gets rid of the timestamp on `getdate()` (despite the name, it has the time as well as the date).

You might find this less confusing if you use `current_timestamp` (which is part of the SQL standard):

```
where SETL.SettlementDate < convert(date, current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try by using cast

```
Select
    SETL.SettlementDay as SD,
    SETL.Amount as Amount,
    SETL.quantity as Q
From
    Setlement as SETL
Where
    cast( SETL.SettlementDate as date) < cast( getdate() as date)
```